# What will be the LINQ equivalent query of SQL GROUP BY statement?

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I have a TSQL statement with GROUP BY. I want to know the equivalent LINQ and lambda expression of this in C#.

```
SELECT ProductId, SUM(QTY)
From Test 
Group BY ProductId
Order BY SUM(QTY) DESC
```

Comment: [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1)?

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ equivalent query will be:

```
var resultsLinq = from test in tests
                  group new { test.QTY } by test.ProductId into prdGroup
                  let qtySum = prdGroup.Sum(t => t.QTY)
                  orderby qtySum descending
                  select new { ProdyctId = prdGroup.Key, QtySum = qtySum };
```

and the lambda equivalent query will be:

```
var resultsLamda = tests
    .GroupBy(test => test.ProductId)                
    .Select(prdGroup => new { ProdyctId = prdGroup.Key, QtySum = prdGroup.Sum(t => t.QTY) })
    .OrderByDescending(prdGroup => prdGroup.QtySum);
```

The full code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Test
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int QTY { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IList<Test> tests = new List<Test>
            {
                new Test { ProductId = 1, QTY = 10 },
                new Test { ProductId = 1, QTY = 20 },
                new Test { ProductId = 1, QTY = 30 },
                new Test { ProductId = 2, QTY = 40 },
                new Test { ProductId = 2, QTY = 50 }
            };

            var resultsLinq = from test in tests
                              group new { test.QTY } by test.ProductId into prdGroup
                              let qtySum = prdGroup.Sum(t => t.QTY)
                              orderby qtySum descending
                              select new { ProdyctId = prdGroup.Key, QtySum = qtySum };

            var resultsLamda = tests
                .GroupBy(test => test.ProductId)                
                .Select(prdGroup => new { ProdyctId = prdGroup.Key, QtySum = prdGroup.Sum(t => t.QTY) })
                .OrderByDescending(prdGroup => prdGroup.QtySum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should swap the order by and select in the method version so you aren't performing the SUM operation 2x

Comment: It's spelled **lambda** - not "lamda" (you were missing a "b" before the "d")

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I got your point. Can you please give an example?

Comment: Something like `GroupBy(c => c.ProductId).Select(c => new { ProductId = c.Key, QtySum = c.Sum(d => d. QTY) }).OrderByDescending(c => c.QtySum)`